# Define conditional breakpoint for access violation

Tags: c++, windbg, breakpoints, access-violation

I want to setup a breakpoint in WinDbg if an access violation happens for a pointer. Is there a way to setup that breakpoint?

Comment: It should already break on all access violations. Are you saying you want to not break on any access violation, *except* when the target is the location pointed to by this pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, WinDbg should already break on first and second chance exceptions of that type. If it doesn't, you must have made a different setting once and then saved that into a workspace which is now loaded. Typical candidate would be the `user default` workspace.

You can change the setting in `Debug / Event Filters ...` menu or with the commands

```
sxe av; *** Enable first chance and second chance exceptions (usually a good choice)
sxd av; *** Enable second chance exceptions
sxr; *** Reset all exception filters to default
```

Another option would be to delete the WinDbg workspaces Registry key at

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windbg\Workspaces
```

while WinDbg is not running. Note that there might be several workspaces deleted. Don't do that if you have put effort in setting up your workspaces. However, in that case I doubt you would have forgotten about the accesss violation setting.